# How can I connect a JDBC azure sql server to android application?

Tags: java, android, database, azure, jdbc

I have been writing an android application in android studio that needs access to a cloud database. I am using Microsoft Azure for my database and have already created it, however I am struggling to query it from the android application. When trying from Android Studio, I get an error to do with JDBC not being found, however I have tried adding the relevant .jar files with no luck. I have also tried creating a maven project as suggested on the Azure site, and with this I can access the database fine, however as soon as I try using the package created by maven as a module in Android Studio, the sql query no longer works and instead goes to the exception. Below you can see the function I am trying to access in the maven project:

```java
    public static ArrayList<Double[]> getIncidentDetails() {

        // Connect to database
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://............"; //Take ............ to be my connection string
        Connection connection = null;

        ArrayList<Double[]> results = new ArrayList<Double[]>();
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            System.out.println("Connected");
            String selectSQL = "SELECT [latitude], [longitude]" + "FROM [Incidents]";

            try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                 ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(selectSQL)) {
                   while (resultSet.next()) {
                     System.out.println(resultSet.getString(2));
                     Double latitude = Double.parseDouble(resultSet.getString(1));
                     Double longitude = Double.parseDouble(resultSet.getString(2));
                     results.add(new Double[] {latitude, longitude});
                   }
                   connection.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
          System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return results;
    }
```

Any ideas on how I could connect to the database from Android Studio, with or without the Maven project would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the class before you open the connection:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that hasn't worked, and instead `null` is printed from the catch statement, suggesting that there isn't even an error message?